# How to change the y ticks label for heatmap with matplotlib plt.imshow?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, heatmap

I am trying to specify the tick location and frequency for y-axis for my heatmap using matplotlib plt.imshow.

I have a sample code below:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

ax.imshow(dFF_snips, cmap= 'hot', interpolation = 'none', aspect = 'auto')
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0.5, len(dFF_snips),1))
ax.set_yticklabels(np.arange(1, len(dFF_snips),1))
```

The `dFF_snip` here is a list with 2 numpy array elements (2x2). The value of `dFF_snip` is below:

```
print (dFF_snips)
[array([-1.8822885 , -1.8549905 , -1.8296311 , -1.8080201 , -1.7912312 ,
       -1.7804587 , -1.7767344 , -1.780715  , -1.7938154 , -1.8149264 ,
       -1.8465863 , -1.8899457 , -1.9409375 , -1.9931413 , -2.0453465 ,
       -2.0977397 , -2.15121   , -2.2029345 , -2.2531028 , -2.3032935 ,
       -2.3565419 , -2.4161592 , -2.479967  , -2.543494  , -2.5983462 ,
       -2.6451566 , -2.6862512 , -2.7176433 , -2.7372882 , -2.747169  ,
       -2.750199  , -2.7498198 , -2.7493978 , -2.7578523 , -2.7844353 ,
       -2.8315635 , -2.9044938 , -3.0043793 , -3.1294305 , -3.277962  ,
       -3.4421551 , -3.6112301 , -3.7806895 , -3.9461625 , -4.0972414 ,
       -4.2289515 , -4.3385363 , -4.424823  , -4.4883513 , -4.532503  ,
       -4.5646443 , -4.58944   , -4.6088505 , -4.6220293 , -4.6342707 ,
       -4.6473126 , -4.661791  , -4.6782117 , -4.696537  , -4.7196736 ,
       -4.7511196 , -4.7927513 , -4.8435016 , -4.89862   , -4.9564075 ,
       -5.0158553 , -5.0760636 , -5.1353955 , -5.1895895 , -5.238624  ,
       -5.2806144 , -5.3163066 , -5.3447247 , -5.36642   , -5.3814077 ,
       -5.3881364 , -5.3849244 , -5.3705726 , -5.3448462 , -5.308451  ,
       -5.2625375 , -5.207037  , -5.1442537 , -5.080445  , -5.0244327 ,
       -4.984356  , -4.9615374 , -4.954831  , -4.9617405 , -4.9791384 ,
       -5.0037413 , -5.0323377 , -5.059078  , -5.0806446 , -5.1011295 ,
       -5.122504  , -5.146725  , -5.175042  , -5.209402  , -5.255945  ,
       -5.314746  , -5.379836  , -5.44777   , -5.516466  , -5.583969  ,
       -5.648302  , -5.7048216 , -5.752765  , -5.7887063 , -5.811991  ,
       -5.8275847 , -5.8386745 , -5.8451476 , -5.8462815 , -5.8407607 ,
       -5.8266883 , -5.8025455 , -5.768773  , -5.72489   , -5.6673093 ,
       -5.5983315 , -5.5259886 , -5.458761  , -5.403886  , -5.36478   ,
       -5.3438416 , -5.342907  , -5.364466  , -5.404285  , -5.4572835 ,
       -5.517151  , -5.5742135 , -5.621361  , -5.6528864 , -5.6692514 ,
       -5.672536  , -5.6654186 , -5.6482277 , -5.6235633 , -5.599008  ,
       -5.580639  , -5.5739145 , -5.5779624 , -5.589749  , -5.606258  ,
       -5.624993  , -5.6418123 , -5.651057  , -5.6521254 , -5.643853  ,
       -5.627396  , -5.6036816 , -5.5739474 , -5.54002   , -5.5041423 ,
       -5.471208  , -5.445212  , -5.4309144 , -5.4306445 , -5.4438753 ,
       -5.4677343 , -5.498519  , -5.5353036 , -5.57779   , -5.6167226 ,
       -5.6415677 , -5.652169  , -5.6503644 , -5.6396747 , -5.62374   ,
       -5.6030574 , -5.5774198 , -5.5563984 , -5.5467024 , -5.5476923 ,
       -5.5576925 , -5.575279  , -5.602696  , -5.63887   , -5.679612  ,
       -5.717645  , -5.750725  , -5.7775197 , -5.797683  , -5.8123    ,
       -5.8214726 , -5.8264694 , -5.82957   , -5.8367686 , -5.8501425 ,
       -5.8717527 , -5.904425  , -5.9460497 , -5.994463  , -6.043525  ,
       -6.0860786 , -6.113253  , -6.117045  , -6.0944533 , -6.0426073 ,
       -5.9613705 , -5.853579  , -5.723713  , -5.577989  , -5.425921  ,
       -5.2748075 , -5.133173  , -5.0055504 , -4.893709  , -4.8013916 ,
       -4.729972  , -4.6693077 , -4.613176  , -4.5573344 , -4.4992185 ,
       -4.4381495 , -4.374554  , -4.305001  , -4.221483  , -4.1239524 ,
       -4.0080414 , -3.8665266 , -3.6785667 , -3.435253  , -3.1269002 ,
       -2.7396197 , -2.2662575 , -1.7103218 , -1.0797501 , -0.38504073,
        0.35231286,  1.1085372 ,  1.8604275 ,  2.5868106 ,  3.2650638 ,
        3.88009   ,  4.427451  ,  4.9026966 ,  5.310102  ,  5.659054  ,
        5.959997  ,  6.22682   ,  6.480126  ,  6.7403393 ,  7.0139074 ,
        7.307172  ,  7.6194806 ,  7.9485364 ,  8.29129   ,  8.642674  ,
        8.998259  ,  9.352926  ,  9.700551  , 10.040269  , 10.36643   ,
       10.67472   , 10.964947  , 11.2369175 , 11.491209  , 11.728639  ,
       11.951131  , 12.161948  , 12.36541   , 12.567936  , 12.771758  ,
       12.978437  , 13.188399  , 13.404184  , 13.626745  , 13.853698  ,
       14.082246  , 14.31026   , 14.528476  , 14.727809  , 14.900687  ,
       15.04402   , 15.156785  , 15.238539  , 15.289807  , 15.313582  ,
       15.31713   , 15.304714  , 15.280266  , 15.253396  , 15.230518  ,
       15.2263775 , 15.250487  , 15.304828  , 15.393541  , 15.515712  ,
       15.665333  , 15.832893  , 16.00457   , 16.16947   , 16.310741  ,
       16.4211    , 16.498234  , 16.541042  , 16.551107  , 16.532488  ,
       16.48923   , 16.435703  , 16.389143  , 16.365812  , 16.367193  ,
       16.396809  , 16.45823   , 16.546036  , 16.654066  , 16.765757  ,
       16.868177  , 16.948336  , 17.008982  , 17.0496    , 17.063437  ,
       17.050173  , 17.011639  , 16.94833   , 16.86501   , 16.769604  ,
       16.666597  , 16.55239   , 16.431707  , 16.311302  , 16.192154  ,
       16.071764  , 15.948116  , 15.819756  , 15.679544  , 15.523486  ,
       15.347094  , 15.156804  , 14.95653   , 14.751297  , 14.546366  ,
       14.34639   , 14.158085  , 13.986786  , 13.839194  , 13.715297  ,
       13.609531  , 13.519229  , 13.4388895 , 13.362569  , 13.286026  ,
       13.202943  , 13.1025715 , 12.980316  , 12.842534  , 12.69255   ,
       12.53745   , 12.386539  , 12.245493  , 12.122852  , 12.022797  ,
       11.948581  , 11.900274  , 11.871156  , 11.856454  , 11.848497  ,
       11.840949  , 11.829887  , 11.810318  , 11.782139  , 11.745777  ,
       11.701197  , 11.652182  , 11.606136  , 11.566988  , 11.545708  ,
       11.550325  , 11.581249  , 11.63827   , 11.719916  , 11.819736  ,
       11.932257  , 12.054184  , 12.182194  , 12.313297  , 12.445502  ,
       12.580897  , 12.724497  , 12.875883  , 13.036144  , 13.204837  ,
       13.381885  , 13.571632  , 13.775131  , 13.997929  , 14.24062   ,
       14.498061  , 14.769052  , 15.05298   , 15.349015  , 15.654352  ,
       15.96401   , 16.27362   , 16.577772  , 16.861462  , 17.122467  ,
       17.346304  , 17.518572  , 17.634878  , 17.694998  , 17.69741   ],
      dtype=float32), array([14.985913 , 15.0813265, 15.201618 , 15.339931 , 15.482807 ,
       15.622314 , 15.745328 , 15.845537 , 15.918395 , 15.9597025,
       15.970337 , 15.947713 , 15.892259 , 15.816352 , 15.728424 ,
       15.637668 , 15.560816 , 15.501743 , 15.459493 , 15.435576 ,
       15.427354 , 15.428045 , 15.4214325, 15.392995 , 15.336227 ,
       15.245654 , 15.122533 , 14.969285 , 14.797668 , 14.618191 ,
       14.441152 , 14.280328 , 14.139093 , 14.0161085, 13.906187 ,
       13.803871 , 13.704677 , 13.60463  , 13.495758 , 13.374351 ,
       13.240541 , 13.095286 , 12.940205 , 12.779708 , 12.619321 ,
       12.462998 , 12.321359 , 12.195814 , 12.088715 , 12.001717 ,
       11.93776  , 11.897891 , 11.875162 , 11.860579 , 11.854521 ,
       11.849422 , 11.838185 , 11.81166  , 11.767702 , 11.707357 ,
       11.63462  , 11.555485 , 11.47481  , 11.405646 , 11.3603325,
       11.349787 , 11.386207 , 11.469798 , 11.596573 , 11.758874 ,
       11.950013 , 12.1582575, 12.373628 , 12.59353  , 12.812452 ,
       13.027382 , 13.238621 , 13.446201 , 13.648696 , 13.844095 ,
       14.030461 , 14.206606 , 14.369981 , 14.51379  , 14.634885 ,
       14.732284 , 14.803246 , 14.850707 , 14.876606 , 14.882255 ,
       14.869549 , 14.843523 , 14.812805 , 14.780341 , 14.750411 ,
       14.726697 , 14.708117 , 14.692233 , 14.676164 , 14.656219 ,
       14.62422  , 14.574705 , 14.508799 , 14.428904 , 14.338353 ,
       14.241846 , 14.147425 , 14.056105 , 13.969798 , 13.888433 ,
       13.809785 , 13.7317505, 13.647875 , 13.554984 , 13.459616 ,
       13.367651 , 13.285801 , 13.220657 , 13.178888 , 13.16811  ,
       13.188882 , 13.240819 , 13.322815 , 13.431261 , 13.553786 ,
       13.677812 , 13.796276 , 13.909011 , 14.012255 , 14.100053 ,
       14.173452 , 14.236986 , 14.291727 , 14.335081 , 14.364861 ,
       14.378245 , 14.3722725, 14.340262 , 14.273232 , 14.167559 ,
       14.023277 , 13.839618 , 13.621736 , 13.374201 , 13.106571 ,
       12.829431 , 12.557793 , 12.303619 , 12.074016 , 11.874444 ,
       11.711173 , 11.5863495, 11.495105 , 11.428545 , 11.382363 ,
       11.346231 , 11.316199 , 11.289666 , 11.261737 , 11.225497 ,
       11.176408 , 11.108545 , 11.014187 , 10.8888645, 10.731119 ,
       10.541812 , 10.3226   , 10.077124 ,  9.811858 ,  9.543706 ,
        9.282138 ,  9.026755 ,  8.78138  ,  8.547419 ,  8.322434 ,
        8.101543 ,  7.8811502,  7.658479 ,  7.4329863,  7.203424 ,
        6.967441 ,  6.726277 ,  6.48304  ,  6.2404237,  5.999122 ,
        5.763114 ,  5.5331116,  5.308862 ,  5.08791  ,  4.866709 ,
        4.6443095,  4.4183106,  4.1867266,  3.9511278,  3.714395 ,
        3.484849 ,  3.2739005,  3.0899024,  2.9358234,  2.8153837,
        2.727375 ,  2.6660771,  2.6191638,  2.5712247,  2.5117695,
        2.4352205,  2.3356235,  2.2147193,  2.0792274,  1.9332346,
        1.786934 ,  1.6477907,  1.5201409,  1.4157685,  1.335785 ,
        1.2748284,  1.2278844,  1.1929066,  1.1664782,  1.1425498,
        1.119881 ,  1.0991426,  1.0819967,  1.0758952,  1.0952543,
        1.153253 ,  1.2662036,  1.4550017,  1.7340628,  2.107755 ,
        2.5685928,  3.1026032,  3.6955702,  4.318763 ,  4.9410887,
        5.533783 ,  6.070261 ,  6.528496 ,  6.8935337,  7.161574 ,
        7.333489 ,  7.4176044,  7.427965 ,  7.379712 ,  7.2934084,
        7.191278 ,  7.0916743,  7.008934 ,  6.9526563,  6.9229813,
        6.916075 ,  6.9264   ,  6.9488316,  6.9789352,  7.0105314,
        7.0356383,  7.0489025,  7.0510798,  7.044831 ,  7.0329638,
        7.020595 ,  7.0151157,  7.0165215,  7.0248165,  7.042253 ,
        7.071152 ,  7.1211853,  7.199633 ,  7.3065066,  7.4405656,
        7.5979733,  7.773173 ,  7.9608345,  8.157463 ,  8.361792 ,
        8.57324  ,  8.790566 ,  9.011866 ,  9.235196 ,  9.454955 ,
        9.658838 ,  9.834555 ,  9.972411 , 10.064418 , 10.109178 ,
       10.105817 , 10.05925  ,  9.97626  ,  9.865885 ,  9.746819 ,
        9.631683 ,  9.533817 ,  9.45777  ,  9.404203 ,  9.372148 ,
        9.363664 ,  9.377956 ,  9.412059 ,  9.457245 ,  9.508495 ,
        9.563546 ,  9.620097 ,  9.673766 ,  9.71818  ,  9.752294 ,
        9.775398 ,  9.7845125,  9.78442  ,  9.776973 ,  9.763239 ,
        9.744236 ,  9.721276 ,  9.696176 ,  9.674806 ,  9.662116 ,
        9.663079 ,  9.684327 ,  9.726172 ,  9.786347 ,  9.859422 ,
        9.939408 , 10.018817 , 10.077755 , 10.101078 , 10.084569 ,
       10.019482 ,  9.903698 ,  9.7449465,  9.552645 ,  9.336995 ,
        9.121732 ,  8.917354 ,  8.732036 ,  8.578597 ,  8.459781 ,
        8.375313 ,  8.325781 ,  8.30734  ,  8.313846 ,  8.335098 ,
        8.359409 ,  8.379589 ,  8.386902 ,  8.377978 ,  8.352097 ,
        8.308868 ,  8.243141 ,  8.151444 ,  8.034054 ,  7.8960104,
        7.7449217,  7.585512 ,  7.421139 ,  7.254254 ,  7.0934505,
        6.9450407,  6.811127 ,  6.6935964,  6.592676 ,  6.5094566,
        6.4417987,  6.390399 ,  6.3554926,  6.3369603,  6.3329616,
        6.3431134,  6.3648477,  6.3899426,  6.416245 ,  6.4398155,
        6.457299 ,  6.461171 ,  6.4458175,  6.408045 ,  6.3481317,
        6.2683845,  6.1794457,  6.086313 ,  5.9965906,  5.917904 ,
        5.8516035,  5.8051486,  5.7863135,  5.794681 ,  5.8297243,
        5.8908987,  5.980261 ,  6.0962725,  6.232703 ,  6.386052 ,
        6.5428267,  6.6911154,  6.823757 ,  6.93193  ,  7.0096216,
        7.0513644,  7.0608153,  7.04208  ,  7.004848 ,  6.956893 ,
        6.9008403,  6.848636 ,  6.808554 ,  6.785692 ,  6.781085 ],
      dtype=float32)]
```

I got the result below:
[image]

But this is not what I want and obviously it hides my data.

I am looking for something more like this (I draw with illustrator):
[image]

Thank you so much!

Comment: When i run your code i get the image output that you want

Answer (score 0):

Change `set_yticks` to `[0,1]` or `range(len(dFF_snips))`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(dFF_snips, cmap= 'hot', interpolation = 'none', aspect = 'auto')
ax.set_yticks([0,1])
```

[image]